# как полностью удалить MS SQL Server, если он был установлен некорректно?

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь установить 2019 версию mssql server-а, предыдущей стояла 17.

Ситуация отображена на скрине - при попытке вызвать mssql server для дальнейшего удаления виндовс говорит, что он мог быть уже удалён. если удалить остальные компоненты и попытаться заново запустить установочник- ситуация не изменится. Соответственно запустить sqlexpress не выходит.
Единственным решением вижу- удалить без остатков mssql server. на как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Помогла эта статья. (если при копировании/вставке powerShell будет ругаться- вводите вручную)
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/